# Get selected value of TCombobox in Delphi RAD Studio 10

Tags: delphi, tcombobox, rad-studio

How to get the selected value from a `TComboBox`?

The `TCombobox` name is `comboTest`

```
vaue_is := comboTest ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ItemIndex:

```
if comboTest.ItemIndex >= 0 then
  vaue_is := comboTest.Items[comboTest.ItemIndex];
```

This should work equally well for VCL and FireMonkey (FMX).

Comment: Velthus  Tnx for help but in ShowMessage(vaue_is ); I get name no value eg. 100

Comment: You get a string, right. What "value" do you want to get?

Comment: Yes, value  eg. 100 or 101

Comment: @Pointer, add list of your values you expect to get in your question, because Rudy answer works well.

Comment: @Pointer When you populated the combo you converted the integer values into strings. When you read from the combo, you get those strings back. See if you can think about the problem that you now face. You have a string. You want an integer. How do you solve this problem?

Comment: What does that 100 or 101 signify? the index of the selected item? That is ItemIndex? I answered that already. To display it: `ShowMessageFmt('%d', [comboTest.ItemIndex]);`.

Comment: And if you did what David said, then I don't understand your comment "I get name no value". Did you mean you got a string like `'100'` or something else, i.e. the string you selected? In other words: you should be a little clearer what you actually want to achieve. You could put the relevant code and declarations in your question (**no link**, actual code), so people can understand what you actually want.

Comment: I combo fill from database, eg. value 100 --> Audi, 101 --> Bmw in combo stay Audi, Bmw how get id from that no index. When select Audi I need get '100'.

Comment: So the strings in your combobox are 'Audi', 'BMW', etc.? And now you want to get back the id that was used in the database? You could store that id together with the string, e.g. in the Objects part of the TStrings. Or you get the string like I showed ('Audi') and then search the database for the id. **And that you wanted this is not at all clear from your question**.

Comment: Yes string is Audi or Bmw and I need id from database, I'm bind combo wit odac control.

Comment: That is information that should be in your question. I answered what you actually asked, but what you really want is a little more involved. So add that information to your question and perhaps someone will be able to help you retrieving the id (or the entire record) from the string. Your question does not mention binding, nor anything about an ID from a database. That changes the whole question.

Comment: Tnx for answer, I'm create new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404766/get-selected-id-from-tcombobox-delphi-10-rad-studio   +1 vote for you